# datatables tabletools pdf excel not working when table is in external HTML loaded in page by jquery load?

Tags: jquery, pdf, datatables, export, tabletools

Using jQuery datatables 1.10.5 and tableTools 2.2.3 All three buttons work when my DIV containing datatable is **directly on my page.**

However, I have code that runs in document.ready that loads **external HTML page** (widget component) and creates datatable in one of it's div from AJAX data.
**I have problem with export (pdf and xls) buttons.** Print works. I have checked the SWF path is correct. PDF and excel buttons show but clicking them doesn't nothing.

I tried the following after table is constructed but no luck.

```
var tableInstances = TableTools.fnGetMasters(), instances = tableInstances.length;
while (instances--)
{
    var dataTable = tableInstances[instances];
    if (dataTable.fnResizeRequired())
    {
        dataTable.fnResizeButtons();
    }
}
```

I also tried genering the datatable in DIV that's right on the page and then move the div using detach to the widget area but pdf/xls still don't work.

Please help.

My datatable code:

```
$(fltStart + "#" + aStrTableEleID).unbind();
$(fltStart + "#" + aStrTableEleID).dataTable({
    //having caption div for title info
    dom: 'fTrtip',
    tableTools: {
        "sSwfPath": "Resources/jQ_DataTables_1_10_5/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "pdf",
                "sFileName": "Title" + ".pdf",
                "sTitle": "Title",
                "sButtonText": "PDF",
                "sToolTip": "Click once and wait...",
                "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                "mColumns": "visible",
                "fnComplete": function () {
                    alert("Export completed.\r\n" + "Please open the file from where you saved it.");
                }
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "xls",
                "sFileName": "Title" + ".csv",
                "sButtonText": "Excel",
                "sToolTip": "Click once and wait...",
                "mColumns": "visible",
                "fnComplete": function () {
                    alert("Export completed.\r\n" + "Please open the file from where you saved it.");
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "pageLength": 20,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "bStateSave": false,
    "aaSorting": [[aIntSortCol, aStrSortOrder]],

    "aaData":aDtAOData,
    "aoColumns":aDtAOCols

});
```

Comment: you have a mixture of legacy and current versions of DataTables in your code, for example TableTools has been retired and most the prefixes suct and b in bSort has been removed.

Comment: `bSort`  and the like (hungarian notation) is not "removed", but camelcase notation is now encouraged. dataTables still uses the hungarian notation internally, camelcase-names is just mapped over to the old names, and introduction of new features only have a camelcase name.

Comment: But yes, it is hard to see the point by using dataTables 1.10.5 *and* retired TableTools. For example: Flash is now disabled (or is not supported at all) on most browsers and devices, so it is really a dead end.